# Ordering with two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm doing an order on all fields of a table (depending on the user's choice), however one column of that table contains a category (stored as an abbreviation) and those abbreviations are defined in a second table. How can I sort by category name? Example of the table structures below:

Table 1

```
title | amount | category_abbreviation
```

Table 2 -> for category

```
category_name | category_abbreviation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the tables and order on a field from the second table.

```
SELECT * from table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.category_abbreviation = table2.category_abbreviation
ORDER BY table2.category_name
```

Comment: There's an error in that. Should be `INNER JOIN table2` instead.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the error. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and run your query from that:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.title, Table1.amount, Table1.category_abbreviation, Table2.category_name
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.category_abbreviation = Table2.category_abbreviation
```

and use that as your datasource. Or just use the SQL as your datasource, however you are doing it.

You don't have to select the Table2.category_name though if you didn't want to

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT   t1.* 
FROM     Table_1 T1 
JOIN     Table_2 T2
ON       T1.category_abbreviation=T2.category_abbreviation
ORDER BY T2.category_name
```